# Propiedad overflow dentro de uno de los hijos de un elemento con altura fija

Tags: html, css

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de configurar la propiedad overflow de `p` dentro del resto de la sección (sin considerar h4 en el ejemplo):

```css
section {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}

p {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h4>Título</h4>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo a un `<p>` jamás le daría un scroll, se lo daría a su padre. Imagínate que tu texto quieres que tenga varias párrafos (que son varios `<p>` pero quieres que el conjunto de esos párrafos no excedan los 100px). Pore eso, en tu `<section>` lo que hice fue crear una cabecera y un cuerpo, para que sea ese cuerpo el que tenga el scroll y dejando la cabecera fuera de este. Así podrías meter lo que quieras dentro del cuerpo para incluirse en el scroll.

```css
section {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.cuerpo {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="cabecera">
    <h4>Título</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="cuerpo">
    <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
  </div>
  
  
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

El valor de `overflow` debería estar en la etiqueta padre que contiene al párrafo pues si se lo aplicas directo al párrafo:

El padre quedaría desbordado por el contenido de los mismos asumiendo que existan de forma posterior mas etiquetas `p` con contenido por mostrar.

Lo que puedes hacer es quitarlo del `p` y asignarle un `overflow-y` con un valor de `scroll/auto` al section así quedan los eventuales párrafos dentro de el y con la barra de desplazamiento vertical podrías moverte al contenido inferior de esa etiqueta:

```html
    <style>
    section {
      background: lightgrey;
      width: 400px;
      height: 150px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    
    p {
     
    }
    </style>
    <section>
      <h4>Título</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
        software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
        <h4>Título</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
        software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que se refleje el `scroll` en `p` sólo con `css` bastaría con añadirle altura.

```css
section {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}

p {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height:70%
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h4>Título</h4>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
</section>
```